# a class-key must be declared when declaring a friend

Tags: c++, friend

The g++ compiler complains with this error when I declare a friend thusly:

```
friend MyClass;
```

instead of

```
friend class MyClass;
```

Why should the **class** keyword be required?
(the Borland C++ compiler, BTW, does not require it.)

Couldn't the compiler simply look-up MyClass in the symbol table and tell it was declared as a class? (it is obviously doing the look-up anyway because it complains when MyClass it not declared)

It is not like it is making a forward declaration of the class: I still have to have either declared the class above or at least have forward declared it.

It would make sense to me (would be great actually) if

```
friend class MyClass;
```

makes a forward declaration if needed, otherwise it just seems like syntactic salt to me.

I have been merrily using **friend** statements without the **class** or **struct** keyword with no compiler complaints for almost 20 years. 
Is this something fairly new?

Comment: 20 years! You must have been working with Bjorn.

Comment: I used C-Front when I was in graduate school about 1989. I've used mostly Borland C++ since about 1991.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was surprised about this (and as a result deleted a previous incorrect answer).  The C++03 standard says in 11.4:

> An elaborated-type-specifier shall  be  used  in  a  friend  declaration  for  a  class.

Then to make sure there's no misunderstanding, it footnotes that with:

> The class-key of the elaborated-type-specifier is required.

GCC is the only compiler that I have that complains about the missing class-key, but it looks like other compilers are letting us get away with something non-standard...

Now as for the rationale - you'd have to ask someone who knows more about compilers (or standards) than I do.

Comment: `friend` without class-key works under g++ 4.7.0/4.7.3 with option `-std=c++11`

Comment: It would be better If you update your answer according to C++11 also, C++11 has introduced __extended friend declarations__ . See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/introduction_to_the_c_11_feature_extended_friend_declaration3?lang=en

Answer (score 22):

To the point of your question, **because it is the way ISO/IEC 14882:2003 specifies it**  (section 7.1.4).  The `friend` construct is essentially specified as:

```
friend <declaration>
```

where `<declaration>` is the valid declaration of a class, struct, template, or function.

Thus,

```
MyClass;
```

is not a valid declaration, whereas:

```
class MyClass;
```

or:

```
struct MyClass;
```

are.

Idem for, correspondingly:

```
friend class MyClass;
```

or

```
friend struct MyClass;
```

Comment: And if `MyClass` is a class template, the `friend` declaration requires the `template` also