# How to resolve "class must be used when declaring a friend" error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dev-c++, friend-function

```
class two;
class one
{
    int a;
    public:
        one()
        {
            a = 8;
        }
    friend two;
};

class two
{
    public:
        two() { }
        two(one i)
        {
            cout << i.a;
        }
};

int main()
{
    one o;
    two t(o);
    getch();
}
```

I'm getting this error from Dev-C++:

```
a class-key must be used when declaring a friend
```

But    it    runs    fine    when    compiled    with    Microsoft     Visual    C++    compiler.

Comment: Er, please can you fix the formatting! I tried, but it was too hard.

Comment: Please could you fix your whitespace.

Comment: One note, don't use Dev-C++, it's outdated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need

```
 friend class two;
```

instead of

```
 friend two;
```

Also, you don't need to forward-declare your class separately, because a friend-declaration is itself a declaration. You could even do this:

```
//no forward-declaration of two
class one
{
   friend class two;
   two* mem;
};

class two{};
```

Comment: thanxx for the help but y i was'nt getting error with visual c++ compiler

Comment: @desprado07: Well, because many compilers are not exactly strict with this rule (that the word class or struct be present in the friend declaration). It is however mandated by the standard as per 11.4. The accepted answer to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656948/a-class-key-must-be-declared-when-declaring-a-friend) may help you.

Comment: It's allowed to be omitted in C++11

Answer (score 5):

Your code has:

```
friend two;
```

Which should be:

```
friend class two;
```