# VS2010 Compiler define

Tags: c++, visual-studio, conditional-compilation

In gcc I am writting `friend class FriendMaker<T>::Type` but Visual Studio wants `friend FriendMaker<T>::Type`. So I think it is time to go compiler specific.

So What I need to `ifdef` for `Visual Studio` ? I am using 2010 at the moment but I may switch to 2012 latter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the macro [`_MSC_VER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx). To check if the compiler is VS2010, or above:

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1600
```

The following are values for the different versions of VS:

- VS 2003 (VC7.1): `1310`
- VS 2005 (VC8): `1400`
- VS 2008 (VC9): `1500`
- VS 2010 (VC10): `1600`
- VS 2012 (VC11): `1700`

Comment: @NeelBasu, see the linked page. That is what Microsoft decided.

Comment: So Can I Safely make it `1600 <= _MSC_VER` such that It also supports the latter versions ?

Comment: But the last edit doesn't `filter VS2010 and above` that previous one was doing.

Comment: No issues I personally prefer `_MSC_VER >= 1600` but as the answer author used the reverse one. I mentioned it that way in comment.

Comment: @NeelBasu, I had originally used `==` in my answer. Putting literals (always `const`) on the left of equality checks is just a habit from code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `friend class ...` syntax for both compilers.  The `friend ...` syntax, without the `class` keyword, is actually invalid; VS2010 is incorrect in not complaining about it.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/656948/827263).

Comment: Hmm. I just tried this with Visual C++ 2010 Express: `class One { friend class Two; }; class Two { friend class One; }; int main() { One o1; Two o2; }`, and it merely warned about the unused variables. What exactly is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use following code for cross compiler:

```
template <typename T> class B;

template <typename T>
class A
{
    friend typename B<T>::V;
};
```