# Access of nested classes (which behave like friends, but aren't)

Tags: c++, class, instance, parent-child

Without long delay, here the code which I have no clue why it does what it does:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
private:
  void print() { std::cout << "A.print() called" << std::endl; };
public:
  template<typename Foo>
  class B; //NOTE: no friend!
public:
  A();
  B<double>*  bd;
  B<int>*     bi;
}; 

template<typename Foo>
class A::B{
  A* callback;
public:
  B(A* a):callback(a){};
  void print() { callback->print(); }; // Why is this working ???
};

A::A():bd(new B<double>(this)),bi(new B<int>(this)){}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  A a;
//   a.print(); // error: ‘void A::print()’ is private
  a.bd->print();
  a.bi->print();

  A::B<char> c(&a);
  c.print();

  A::B<double> d = *a.bd;
  d.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Well, it creates this ouput:

```
A.print() called
A.print() called
A.print() called
A.print() called
```

**But why?**

### Background

I initially started my journey down the rabbit hole when I encountered a problem which I through to have to do with `friend`s. So I read [friend declaration not forward declaring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114956/friend-declaration-not-forward-declaring) (and the mentioned answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890756/how-come-forward-declaration-is-not-needed-for-friend-class-concept/9890827#9890827) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656948/a-class-key-must-be-declared-when-declaring-a-friend/657113#657113)). So while trying to set up an easy example (the result of which you see above), I found that I actually don't seem to need `friend` at all.

### Question

So here is the bottom line question: **Why does an instance of `A::B` have access to `A`'s private function `A::print()`?** (although I do realize that I might misunderstand what [my children](https://stackoverflow.com/a/437507/1984137) are--*children* as opposed to *base* vs. *derived*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because nested class is a member of the enclosing class

standard $11.7.1

"A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member. The members of an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules shall be obeyed"

and the usual access rules specify that:

"A member of a class can also access all the names to which the class has access..."

specific examples has been given in the standard:

```
class E {
    int x;
    class B { };

    class I {
        B b; // OK: E::I can access E::B
        int y;
        void f(E* p, int i) {
            p->x = i; // OK: E::I can access E::x
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A nested class (or inner class) has access to the privates of the class it is nested within. It is in some sense already friends with that class. It is similar to the way that any `A` object has access to the privates of any other `A` object.

You use `friend` for classes that are defined outside of your class that you want to access its privates. Here's a simple example of this:

```
struct B;

class A
{
  int x;
  friend struct B;
};

struct B
{
  void someFunc() {
    A a;
    a.x = 5;
  }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  B b;
  b.someFunc();
  return 0;
}
```

Without making `B` a friend of `A`, it would not be able to access `A`'s member `x`.

Comment: Nested classes cannot access the outer class' private members.http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr061.htm

Comment: I am not in front of a machine right now. Would be new to me!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013717/are-inner-classes-in-c-automatically-friends

Comment: @bash.d: That has changed in the language. In C++03 nested classes are not considered *members* with respect to access specifiers, but in C++11 they are *members* just like member functions, and thus have the same access rights that any member function.

Comment: @bash.d Whelp. I didn't know it had changed!

Comment: @sftrabbit so they got both of us ;)