# error: a class-key must be used when declaring a friend in gcc

Tags: gcc, c++98

I get an error with this code

```
struct Foo { };

struct Bar { friend Foo; };

int main() { }
```

> ```
> error: a class-key must be used when declaring a friend
> error: friend declaration does not name a class of function
> ```

According to answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656948/a-class-key-must-be-declared-when-declaring-a-friend) this is just what the standard mandates. However, what puzzles me is that I get the error with gcc 4.4.7 but **not** with the **newer** gcc 4.8.5 (in both cases no compiler flags, but only defaults, ie no C++11). Why is that?

Has gcc decided to drop its standard compliance on this point, because thats what all others compilers do, or what is going on here?

And if possible, I would like to know if I can get gcc 4.8 to issue an error on that (or alternatively make gcc 4.4 swallow it without complaints).

Comment: 4.4.7? Wasn't that decreed null and void by King Charles II? Anyway use `g++ -std=c++98 -pedantic` to get such diagnostic.

Comment: @n.m. if I could choose I would write c++11, unfortunately the job is too interesting even without c++11 :P

Comment: @n.m. with `-pedantic` i get a warning, but thats good enough